# Django nonrel can not retrieve saved Credential via Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, django-nonrel

I'm trying to get the default sample app working in order to use APIs (same as this example):

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/django_sample/plus/views.py

I successfully retrieve the access token, but then my index view handler can not retrieve the Credential that was saved on the callback. This means my view is in an endless redirect loop asking the API for access it already has the whole time:

```
INFO:root:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:oauth2client.client:Successfully retrieved access token
INFO:root:"GET /oauth2callback/?state=1Rwu-LG-cowGmf9UrW6EuzoxNDA5MTY3M&code=4/yaQK1MVKYh9PeSN7OilnYHzdfSf_.An4_j5za2IcboiIBeO6P2m9ej9cxkAI HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:root:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:oauth2client.client:Successfully retrieved access token
INFO:root:"GET /oauth2callback/?state=1Rwu-LG-cowGmf9UrW6EuzoxNDA5MTY3M&code=4/yaQK1MVKYh9PeSN7OilnYHzdfSf_.An4_j5za2IcboiIBeO6P2m9ej9cxkAI HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:root:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO:oauth2client.client:Successfully retrieved access token
INFO:root:"GET /oauth2callback/?state=1Rwu-LG-cowGmf9UrW6EuzoxNDA5MTY3M&code=4/yaQK1MVKYh9PeSN7OilnYHzdfSf_.An4_j5za2IcboiIBeO6P2m9ej9cxkAI HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

I can see that the Credential is successfully stored in the datastore with the correct id of the User. It seems that Storage just can't seem to retrieve it (the `credential` is `None`)

PS: similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059386/storage-of-driveapi-credentials-using-oauth2client-django-orm-storage-class)

**Update**

The token I receive back looks like this:

```
{'revoke_uri': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke',
'access_token': u'ya29.cACFl3-de08MsB0AAADMsAKOc4d06fkI71_YEAfoPWaG84f3PoPiMRUmdSMQw',
'token_uri': u'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
'token_response': {u'access_token': u'ya29.cACFl3-de08MsB0AAADMsAKOc4d06fkI71_YEAfoPWaG84f3PoPiMRUmdSMQw',
                    u'token_type': u'Bearer', u'expires_in': 396,
                    u'id_token': {u'aud': u'1020730626638-fdf06iqdihvr4lbldeg7jd7suuau9rl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                                  u'cid': u'1020730626638-fdf06iqdihvr4lbldeg7jd7suuau9rl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                                  u'iss': u'accounts.google.com', u'at_hash': u'n_NmKydTYbZIEzHVzUg0cw',
                                  u'exp': 1409314030,
                                  u'azp': u'1020730626638-fdf06iqdihvr4lbldeg7jd7suuau9rl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                                  u'iat': 1409310130, u'token_hash': u'n_NmKydTYbZIEzHVzUg0cw',
                                  u'id': u'10694247378316072486', u'sub': u'10694247378316072486'}},
'invalid': False,
'refresh_token': None,
'client_id': u'1020730626638-fdf06iqdihvr4lbldeg7jd7suuau9rl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'id_token': {u'aud': u'1020730626638-fdf06iqdihvr4lbldeg7jd7suuau9rl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
              u'cid': u'1020730626638-fdf06iqdihvr4lbldeg7jd7suuau9rl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
              u'iss': u'accounts.google.com', u'at_hash': u'n_NmKydTYbZIEzHVzUg0cw', u'exp': 1409314030,
              u'azp': u'1020730626638-fdf06iqdihvr4lbldeg7jd7suuau9rl.apps.googleusercontent.com', u'iat': 1409310130,
              u'token_hash': u'n_NmKydTYbZIEzHVzUg0cw', u'id': u'10694247378316072486',
              u'sub': u'10694247378316072486'},
'client_secret': u'8B9ODH3EliQwcXRhF2f3qicN',
'token_expiry': datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 29, 12, 7, 7, 303770),
'store': None,
'user_agent': None
}
```

If i change the callback view handler with the following, by adding an immediate retrieval:

```
credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
storage.put(credential)
credential = storage.get()
```

Then that last credential is `None`

Comment: Are you simply trying to get OAuth working so you can use API's?

Comment: @Bruyere i think the oath is working, it's the Storage class that cannot load the credentials.

Comment: If you want I can show you how to use a Google system that handles the OAuth process. It handles storing and retrieving the credentials, as well as refreshing if needed. It may solve your issue but will involve a slight re-write.

Comment: @Bruyere I won't not mind, but django-nonrel is required though.

Comment: Sorry I spaced when reading that part. If you go to the datastore viewer is there anything listed?

Comment: @Bruyere "I can see that the Credential is successfully stored in the datastore with the correct id of the User."

Comment: Have you tried to get a user after waiting a bit? Eventual consistency might be hitting you here.

Answer (score 0):

I changed primary_key=True to unique=True on the ForeignKey property in the CredentialsModel class.  Once I made this change the Storage object was able to properly get the user's stored credentials.